# Segfaults in new libstdc++ on a legacy system

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, arm

I'm trying to retrofit a current (GCC >= 4.6) toolchain onto a legacy embedded ARM/Linux system based on glibc 2.3.6. I have successfully built the toolchain, but now my test programs are segfaulting in libstdc++, for example:

```
int main()
{
    int* foo = new int[100];
    delete [] foo;
    return 0;
}
```

... segfaults in static initialization of libstdc++:

```
#0  0x40082778 in (anonymous namespace)::__future_category_instance ()
    at /path/to/src/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++-v3/src/future.cc:64
#1  0x40082bb0 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__priority=65535, __initialize_p=1)
    at /path/to/src/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++-v3/src/future.cc:103
#2  _GLOBAL__sub_I_future.cc(void) () at /path/to/src/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++-v3/src/future.cc:109
#3  0x400e92b8 in __do_global_ctors_aux () from /path/to/symbols/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x400627a0 in _init () from /path/to/symbols/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x4000b5e4 in ?? () from /path/to/sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.2
#6  0x4000b5e4 in ?? () from /path/to/sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.2
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I have several more examples, but the crash sites all look similar to this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function (anonymous namespace)::__future_category_instance():
   0x40082764 <+0>: ldr r3, [pc, #264]  ; 0x40082874 <(anonymous namespace)::__future_category_instance()+272>
   0x40082768 <+4>: push    {r11, lr}
   0x4008276c <+8>: add r11, sp, #4
   0x40082770 <+12>:    sub sp, sp, #64 ; 0x40
   0x40082774 <+16>:    mov r1, #0
=> 0x40082778 <+20>:    ldr r3, [r1, r3]
```

I interpret this as the code trying to read from base address 0 (r1 = 0, r3 in this case was 3736), which might hint at a relocation problem?

This particular crash occurs when I build with either `-static`, `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` *or* force loading of the libgcc_s.so.1 and libstdc++.so.6 from my toolchain via LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I'm pretty much stuck here and would appreciate any clues as to what might be wrong with my toolchain, and whether this should work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have now tracked this down to a [change in GCC 4.6.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=168401) that seems to have broken the code generation for the obsolete ABI I'm forced to use here (APCS).

With that change reversed, my test code now runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's either a broken build, or it's trying to load a library from your old system.

You can check the second option by running with `strace` to see what library files it opens:

```
strace your-program
```

This will work fine for a statically linked binary, but is more tricky if you want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because that will most likely break the strace binary. In that case try it like this:

```
strace /path/to/ld-linux.so --library-path /path/to/libraries your-program
```

You'll need to figure out what `ld-linux.so` is called on your system.

Comment: I already checked what gets loaded by setting LD_DEBUG=all, but nothing looked wrong to me.

Comment: Does `LD_DEBUG` cover `libdl`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't think it loads the wrong code, I think the code that it loads is wrong (or loaded in a wrong way...).